# achartengine graph redraws incorrectly when list component below it (not overlapping) is interacted with

Tags: java, android, achartengine, custom-lists

I have a graph that takes up 50% of the screen and a custom list component below it. The graph has zoom and interaction turned off.

If i move the list up and down the graph seems to redraw itself incorrectly, note the graph is not moving up and down the screen, it stays in same position. Its as iff the list is sliding under the graph causing it to incorrectly redraw itself.

Anybody seen this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fix this, just add this line:

```
renderer.setInScroll(true);
```